# Why every time I open the ubuntu file manager, are the hidden files displayed?

Tags: ubuntu, files

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and whenever I open the file manager to see my folders, the hidden files are always displayed, I do not want to show them ... they appear alone, and it is always when I open the file manager.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

use `ctrl + h` to view or hide hidden folders/files in file manager.

Or goto `View -> unselect or select Show Hidden Files` option.